# ASP .NET MVC 5 prevent "escape" Unicode string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unicode

First I'd like to sorry if the title is not correct, I really don't know how to call it. I tried google many times but don't found the need result (maybe my keywords are not correct)

My problem is, in my ASP .NET MVC 5 project, some Unicode words are ""escaped". Ex:Thư viện Trường THPT Chuy&#234;n Lương Thế Vinh (the "Chuyên" was "escaped" to "Chuy&#234;n")

Anyone know solution for this please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you put some code of your view and layout and this value coming from controller or directly coded in the view?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for respnse. Here is my view [link]http://pastebin.com/xx3dLskD
and here is the the generated HTML [link]http://pastebin.com/4mnwLP4E
and here is the layout [link]http://pastebin.com/L3mBKN1b
Please have a look. Thanks a lot.